# Stop event handling by another event

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, telegram

I am developing bot with telegram client api and telethon. I created a command handler.

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, forwards=False, pattern=r'some_pattern'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    send_messages = []
    while True:
        send_messages.append(await client.send_message((await event.get_chat()).id, 'valueable_info'))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

I would like to delete `send_messages` and stop `my_event_handler` execution when `events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, forwards=False, pattern=r'another_pattern')` is triggered. How do i achive that?

Comment: Stop execution of whole bot or only reaction with that handler? How to react instead?

Comment: @wowkin2 Not whole bot, only `my_event_handler` with corresponding `chat_id`

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do that:

```py
ids = []

def start_handler(event):
    ids.append(event.id)
    while event.id in ids:
        do_stuff()

def stop_handler(event):
    try:
        ids.remove(event.id)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```